# Merge two accounts in Cognito created with same email (email and social)

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my app, I have Amazon Cognito Hosted UI configured to handle Authentication by email and social (facebook and google).

**The problem:**

When a user create an account by email (ex: gmail) and later sign up by social (ex: same gmail), I have two accounts created in Cognito.

**Question:**

How merge these two accounts created with the same email?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

For those interested, I created an issue on aws amplify: 
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2754

Comment: You can create a pre-sign up lambda and use `adminLinkProviderForUser` to merge two accounts. Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminLinkProviderForUser.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Amplify: How to map social providers attributes for an email based authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61687229/aws-amplify-how-to-map-social-providers-attributes-for-an-email-based-authentic)

Comment: The anwser is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59642140/1704104

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link them however you can decide the behavior by setting the [forceAliasCreation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmSignUp.html) parameter in ConfirmSignUp API. If you set it as false it will throw an error if a user has already registered with same email/phone number. If you set it as true, the old account will be deactivated and the new one will be the only one he can use. You can read more about this behavior [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233062)